# Angular Universal: Title and meta tags and not updated in Page Source

Tags: angular, angular-universal

In my Angular Universal Application I am trying to update title and meta tags after the api call success.

**app.component.ts**

```
import {Component, Inject, OnInit, PLATFORM_ID} from '@angular/core';
import {Meta, Title} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {isPlatformBrowser} from '@angular/common';
import {TestService} from './test.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private testService: TestService,
              private title: Title,
              private meta: Meta,
              @Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: Object) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    if (isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)) {
      this.testService.getData().subscribe((res: any) => {
        console.log(res);
        this.title.setTitle(res.name);
        this.meta.updateTag({property: 'og:title', content: res.name});
      });
    }
  }
}
```

In the service...

```
  getData() {
    return this.http.get('assets/data.json');
  }
```

Title and tags are updated in inspect element but not in view page source.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `if (isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId))`  condition means that the code after is only executed client side, not while performing SSR. The code displayed in view-source is the code generated by SSR.

You need to remove that condition. And also, `getData` must call an absolute url when using universal

Comment: How could that possible? Without if **(isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId))**, we cannot call **localStorage** functions.

Comment: Well, do not use localStorage when doing SSR.

Comment: Then, what would be the best way to keep user token other than the local storage?

Comment: You have to use cookies

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use this module - ngx-meta

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ngx-meta/core

then, use this in your api call - this.title.setTitle(res.name);

Answer (score 0):

Use the resolver if the api call is having the http request it will be more complex to render the title before route navigation by using the resolve guard you can get the title before the route navigation so SSR will helps to set the title before rendering page by implementing this you can get updated title in view page source! and which you're observing updated title in inspect elements is the title updating after rendering the page